# Can i pair multivalued attribute with an entity?

Tags: database-design

If i have the following scenario.

> Every doctor can diagnose a disease for different patients. A diagnose
>   holds a date and disease(multi valued attribute). So the patient has
>   testing that need to be done with investigation, the investigation
>   holds type, description and title and testing holds date. For each
>   investigation we know the disease that need to be investigated, hence
>   one disease can have multiple investigations.

This is the sentence where i have difficulties

> For each investigation we know the disease that need to be investigated, hence one disease can have multiple investigations.

I have the following diagram so far. My question is can i connect multivalued disease with Investigation entity? I am new to EER diagrams

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You could create a table for Diseases:

```
TABLE disease
-------------
disease.id (PK)
disease.name
```

Then you can model Diagnosis (note that's a junction table) this way:

```
TABLE diagnosis
---------------
diagnosis.id (PK)
diagnosis.date
diagnosis.doctor_id (FK)
diagnosis.patient_id (FK)
diagnosis.disease_id (FK)
```

So you can add a Disease to an Investigation:

```
TABLE investigation
-------------------
investigation.id (PK)
investigation.type
investigation.title
investigation.description
investigation.disease_id (FK)
```

And finally, here's the table for Testing:

```
TABLE testing
-------------
testing.id (PK)
testing.date
testing.investigation_id (FK)
testing.patient_id (FK)
```

The Testing can as well be included as a field in Investigation instead of having its own table, unless the exercise requires it.

Then there are the tables for Doctor and Patient which you already modeled.

This is the description of the tables, from it you can easily create the ER diagram, remembering that a FK on a table connects to the PK on another table.